# ReactJS Action based on current tab state

Tags: reactjs

I have a UI where i have 5 tabs.
For all these tabs , most part is same but the URL it needs to hit to get its data is a bit different.
So lets take the followng.
To get data for tab1 , it needs to hit following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/tab1_data
```

For second , it needs to hit the following

```
http://localhost:8080/tab2_data
```

I have a single Action which go and gets this data from the URL.

Now , we can get the current tab state from the router , but I am confused if its OK to store this state in the action.
As in when each compnent mounts , I will go and update the state in the Action class.
Does this look like an anti pattern for React ?

Comment: You're using react-router? I didn't really follow the last paragraph, can you show some code?

Comment: Yes , i am using react router...

Comment: Yes, storing state in actions looks like an anti pattern for React. Why not keep it in the store?